# Java - Loops and Specific Characters

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I need to have the program loop until the end of the file. With each run of the loop, it is supposed to capture the student's name and test scores. The way the program is supposed to know that it's reached the end of the student's scores is when it finds "-1." Then it's supposed to find their average, and letter grade. At the end, the program is supposed to print out a file with a summary for the entire class.

I've gotten it to work for the first student, but now I need to make it work until the end of the file. I know this probably isn't the most efficient way to go about this, but it's the only way I could think of.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {        
    //Declare String Variables
    String name = null;
    String grade;
    String inFile;
    String outFile;
    PrintWriter outputFile;

    //Declare Numerical Variables
    double score1 = 0;
    double score2 = 0;
    double score3 = 0;
    double score4 = 0;
    double score5 = 0;
    double score6 = 0;
    double score7 = 0;
    double score8 = 0;
    double count = 0;
    double average;


    //Capture Student Info
    while(scanFile.hasNext()){
        name = scanFile.nextLine();
        if (scanFile.hasNextInt()){
            score1 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score1 == -1){

            }
                break;
            else if (score1 != -1)
                score2 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score2 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score2 != -1)
                score3 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score3 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score3 != -1)
                score4 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score4 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score4 != -1)
                score5 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score5 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score5 != -1)
                score6 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score6 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score6 != -1)
                score7 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
            if (score7 == -1){
                count--;
                break;
            }
            else if (score7 != -1)
                score8 = scanFile.nextInt();
                count++;
        }
    }
            //Processed data for student
            average = findAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, count);
            grade = letterGrade(average);

            //Printing Output File
                      outputFile.print("Grade Report for Introduction to Programming I\n\n");
                      outputFile.print("This program will process test scores.");
                    //Output
                printFile(outputFile, name, count, average, grade);
                //}
            outputFile.close();
        }
```

Sample Input File

```
 John Sweet
 87 76 90 100 -1
 Ali Hassan
 -1
 Willy Nilly
 73 63 74 70 -1
 Juju Smith Jr.
 89 90 78 88 -1
 Karl Kavington III
 90 100 80 70 -1
 Lary Howard Holiday
 80 77 67 67 -1
 Leo Gordon
 56 88 780 77 -1
 Jessy Brown
 -1
 Mr. Perfect
 100 100 100 100 -1
 Mr. Missing It All
 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1
```

Comment: Do you know interface `java.util.List` and its implementations such as `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: Does this code even compile? I would be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your goal would be to get the average grade of each student, in which case, the code would be something like this (instead of your "manual loop" method):

```
while(scanFile.hasNext()){ //get average of each student
    name = scanFile.nextLine();
    double count = 0, totalScore = 0;
    while (scanFile.hasNextInt()){
        totalScore = scanFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    double average = findAverage(totalScore, count);
    //Processed data for student
    grade = letterGrade(average);
}
```

Notice I have changed how you call the `findAverage` method, it should be fairly simple to change that in your code. After getting the average, do whatever you need to do with them.

I think you are still having trouble with the basic loops in Java, I recommend reading more about how to use them, here's a [recommendation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/).